# Trying to access gameobjects from other loaded scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, entity-component-system

Basically, i have a player script in DontDestroyOnLoad(), and i have other gameobjects (enemies) that i want to access from the other loaded scene.

```
        foreach(Enemy enemy in FindObjectsOfType<Enemy>()) {
 //Does stuff here
}
```

and its not because of something in the enemy class, as i have tried to do the same with a MapVar class, even trying using singletons. NOTHING WORKS!

I tried singletons, findobjectoftype, tried doing some scene.magickery.

Comment: Just a heads up, I don't think this will fix your problem: You should use `FindObjectsByType<T>` instead. `FindObjectsOfType<T>` is deprecated and will be removed in the future. [Source](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/280b05a874443464be435c70f26644d1703e272a/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs#L302)

Comment: There is no definition for ByType, only OfType.

Comment: There should be, depending on your version: [Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsByType.html)

Comment: Well im using 2021.1.17f, so maybe thats why, ill try to upgrade the version, im using github so if something goes wrong ill probably be fine.

Comment: Ok so i upgraded and it still just returns null

Comment: I figured it out, apparently Singletons do work, if you use them correctly, i now have a MapVariables class, and it works now because instead of trying to say MapVariables.GetEnemies() and calling FindObjectOfType in there, i just call it at the awake and make a permanemt list.